# Actual reason not showing on Firebase Crashlytics for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I have added firebase Crashlytics in my swift project, and it is showing the crashes on the firebase console as well, but my problem is it is not showing the crash reason. It is showing the line number, function name and stack trace but it is not showing the reason in the console.

Please see the screenshots: 
[image]

[image]

But if I make it crash by writing some crash code by myself, it is showing the reason.

[image]

[image]

So my question: Is there any way to show the actual reason for the crash like null assigned on required parameter etc or did I miss something here?

Comment: Hi, Paul from Crashlytics here. If the crash occurs inside a closure, like the one shown above, our tools may not detect the exact line on which it occurred. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you for the information,  can you please confirm does it show proper line number in this case(crash inside a closure)? and is there any way around except changing the code structure? again thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please check if there is any dSYMs file missing in the Crashlytics panel

[image]

Comment: Missing dSYMs will fix symbolication issues, but the two examples he posted are clearly symbolicated, so is not the case here.